# Add a colon after a variable when inputed a value (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my first time coding in python. When I am calling an inputed value within a string, how do I add a colon after that variable? This is what I have so far.

```
name1 = input('Enter name of friend: ')
bill1 = float(input('Enter bill for  '+ name1))
```

For example I want to be able to have this as my result

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQuOW.png)

Comment: `'Enter bill for  '+ name1 + ':'`? Or use one of the proper string formatting methods.

Comment: `f'Enter bill for {name1}: '` ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.6 introduces literal string interpolation:

```
f'Enter bill for {name1}: '
```

For older versions you could use either `format` or `%`:

```
'Enter bill for {}: '.format(name1)
'Enter bill for %s: ' % name1
```

And just string concatenation:

```
'Enter bill for  ' + name1 + ': '
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do:

```
bill1 = float(input("Enter bill for "+str(name)+":"))
```

You can research more into string concatenation in Python.

Comment: `name` is already a string (at least in the example anyway), so need need to cast it.